# How to have one form, two submits with different form elements associated with specific submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form which allows a user to either reject or approve a record. I was trying to design it so there is a checkbox for reject and a checkbox for approve on every row. At the bottom there are two buttons Reject and Approve again. When the user checks approve for one and reject for another and then presses one of the buttons reject or approve that

I was initially hoping to be able to have one button Process which will know when approved is clicked for a record that it will pass it to the approve path and if a reject path is selected it will also know to pass these values to the reject path.

Below is my code so far but I'm not sure how to proceed and whether this is even possible;

```
.block-body
  %table.table.table-striped.sla
    %thead
      %tr.medium
        %th Campaign
        %th Status
        %th Approve
        %th Reject
        %th.notes{:style => "display: none"} Rejection Reason (Required)
    %tbody
      = form_for :campaign do |f|
        - if @campaigns == nil
          = @campaigns.inspect
        - else
          - @campaigns.each do |campaign|
            %tr.medium
              %td= campaign.name
              %td= campaign.status              
              %td
                -if ["New", "Updated"].include? campaign.status  #-if campaign.status != "Approved"
                  = f.check_box :status, {id: "#{campaign.id}", :class => "approvedservices"}, "Approved"
              %td{:style => "width:100px;"}
                -unless ["Rejected", "Approved"].include? campaign.status
                  = f.check_box :status, {id: "reject#{campaign.id}", :class => "rejectedservices"}, "Rejected"
              %td.notes{:style => "display: none"}
                %input{:style => "display: none", :id => "notesrow_#{campaign.id}", :type => "text"}

          %tr.medium
            %td.white{:colspan => 2}
            %td.white{:style => "width:100px;"}
              = submit_tag "First Button", :name => 'first_button'
            %td.white{:style => "width:100px;"}
              = submit_tag "Second Button", :name => 'second_button'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have different submit buttons like this:

In your view:

```
<%= submit_tag t('approve'), name: :commit %>
<%= submit_tag t('reject'), name: :reject %>
```

And in your controller:

```
def create
  do_something if params[:reject] and return
  do_something_else
end
```

Comment: The two actions have different paths and only certain elements in the form relate to the particular paths. How can I accommodate this?